# Data from SharePoint Infopath forms to excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have a SharePoint library having 850 odd infopath forms. I need to export data from all these forms to an excel spreadsheet. Is there any optimized way of doing it without using any utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without using any utility.

Comment: I use Qdabra for some stuff. They have a tool to extract data from IP forms [here](http://www.qdabra.com/en/products/DBXL.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this very successfully using Microsoft Access. The exact steps will depend on how the XML data is formed in InfoPath, but I've done it with both "flat" InfoPath form data as well as InfoPath forms that contain repeating tables. Basically, I map the SharePoint library as a drive letter on my computer, then an Access app iterates through all the InfoPath forms, imports it, and populates tables. From there, if needed, I further tune the data using Access queries and then push the finished data to another Access database that stores the table(s). Finally, I have one or more Excel workbooks -- with pretty pivot tables and charts etc -- that pull their data from the table(s).
At one of my clients, they use this tool I built for them to import and report on about 800 safety reports created in InfoPath every month. Very slick.